# C++: compiler warning C4505 when including header of class derived from class template

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, compiler-warnings

I have the following hierarchy of classes:

```cpp
class FilterMktData
{
   virtual std::vector<std::string> filter(std::vector<std::string>) = 0;
   ...
}
```

```cpp
class FilterMktDataDecorator : public FilterMktData
{
   virtual std::vector<std::string> filter(std::vector<std::string>);
   ...
}
```

```cpp
template<typename T>
class FilterBy : public FilterMktDataDecorator
{
   std::vector<std::string> filter(std::vector<std::string>);
   ...
}
```

```cpp
class FilterByVolume : public FilterBy<int>
{
   ...
}
```

I'm using the decorator pattern. `FilterMktData` is the interface, `FilterMktDataDecorator` is the class that provides an implementation of the interface that delegates the actual work to an inner shared pointer to FilterMktData. This pointer is passed to the constructor.

Now, the class template `FilterBy` implements the filter method by using a lambda expression passed to the constructor (I'm using an argument of type `std::function<bool(T)>`). The idea is to filter the elements that when evaluated return `true`. It was necessary to introduce the template because the elements are `std::string`s and have to be converted before passing them to the lambda expression, and can be anything.

Finally `FilterByVolume` passes a lambda expression to the constructor of `FilterBy<int>` that returns true if the volume is less than a certain value.

I have tested the behavior of the classes and they work as expected. The only problem is that I get the following compiler warning

```
FilterBy.h(51): warning C4505: 'FilterBy<int>::filter' : unreferenced local function has been removed
```

**only** when including in my main.cpp the header file for **FilterByVolume** and not when I include the one for **FilterBy**, even if my main does not instantiate any object of the above classes.

**Question**: how do I get rid of the warning?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This warning is noise. It should never be enabled for C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the warning by putting the following lines in the `.h` file, before the function that causes the problem:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4505)
#endif
```

After that, you can enable that warning again (e.g. for other header files that are not yours):

```
#pragma warning(pop)
```

Note that this pragma is Visual Studio-specific and other compilers may complain about it. So you may want to wrap both in an extra `#ifdef _WIN32` ... `#endif` section.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try with other compilers to see if they give a warning. I'm using CMake for the build and I wouldn't like to see the warning appear when using other compilers.

Comment: g++ will complain about the pragma when compiling with `-Wall` option with warning `ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]`. This can be circumvented by putting the pragmas into a Windows- or MSVC-specific `#ifdef`, e.g. `#ifdef _WIN32`.